# Tail behavior of Fourier transform

Tags: asymptotics, improper-integrals, fourier-transform, upper-lower-bounds

Suppose I have the Fourier transform $\hat f(\omega):= \int_{\mathbb R} f(t) e^{i\omega t} \text dt$ of a certain function $f\in L^2(\mathbb R)$.  I don't necessarily have $f$ in closed form but I have $\hat f$ in closed form.  I am interested in the tail behavior of $\hat f$, i.e.

$$ \bar{\hat{f}}(\omega, x) := \int_x^{\infty} f(t) e^{i\omega t} \text dt $$
for fixed $\omega$ and large $x >> 0$

I assume this has already been studied extensively but a Google search on "Fourier transform tail bound/behavior" did not return much.  Could anyone point me in the right direction for theorems/upper bounds?

Thank you!
p.

Comment: Maybe you want to look at Reimann Lebesgue Lemma.

Comment: Thank you I did not know about this lemma.  Unfortunately it seems to only cover asymptotic behavior of $\hat f$ in the frequency domain $|\omega| \to \infty$ rather than in time/space domain $t$.